# Survey management for multiple forms that can be answered in different times

Tags: windows, wordpress, survey

I have several survey forms, and they shares some duplicate questions. Moreover, one participant can fill the form multiple times. Is there a tool or tool combination to achieve as many of these bullets as possible?

- Answers of different forms of one participant are aggregate into one place
- Each participant doesn't have to answer the same questions in different forms (if a participant has already answer those questions in form A, then they won't be shown in form B, or already has the answer)
- Whenever a participant redoes a same form, then I can track the changes in their answers

It seems that Google Forms doesn't seem to be able to do this.

I use Windows and WordPress. A free software is preferable.

Comment: what is the current format of the forms (pdf)? would you like to keep your format or are you willing to change format to match the tool?

Comment: They are online forms. I'm willing to change the format to match the tool

Comment: forms.google.com?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be able to do this

Comment: If a survey tool allowed a participant to change their answers to a single survey arbitrarily over time, would this suffice?